# How do I create an array of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to create an array of pointers. These pointers will point to a Student object that I created. How do I do it?
What I have now is:

```
Student * db = new Student[5];
```

But each element in that array is the student object, not a pointer to the student object.
Thanks.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
Student** db = new Student*[5];
// To allocate it statically:
Student* db[5];
```

Comment: How is `Student* db[5]` the same thing as `Student** db = new Student*[5]`? What is the benefit of using one over the other?

Comment: When you wish to return an array from a function the array needs to be allocated on the heap. If it s allocated on the stack it is destroyed immediately the scope of that function ends.

Answer (score 20):

```
#include <vector>
std::vector <Student *> db(5);
// in use
db[2] = & someStudent;
```

The advantage of this is that you don't have to worry about deleting the allocated storage - the vector does it for you.

Comment: While vector is the suggested way to have a list of stuff, strictly speaking, it's not an array.

Comment: It can be used in every way that an array can be used. If it quacks like a duck, it's a duck.

Comment: The vector will _not_ delete the allocated storage automatically, it will free the storage for the _pointers_ but not for the memory that the pointer points to. Use boost::ptr_vector for that.

Comment: Did you read my example code? Should the storage pointed to by element [2] be deleted?

Answer (score 12):

An array of pointers is written as a pointer of pointers:

```
Student **db = new Student*[5];
```

Now the problem is, that you only have reserved memory for the five pointers. So you have to iterate through them to create the Student objects themselves.

In C++, for most use cases life is easier with a std::vector.

```
std::vector<Student*> db;
```

Now you can use push_back() to add new pointers to it and [] to index it. It is cleaner to use than the ** thing.

Answer (score -6):

```
    void main()
    {
    int *arr;
    int size;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the integer array:";
    cin>>size;
    cout<<"Creating an array of size<<size<<"\n";
        arr=new int[size];
    cout<<"Dynamic allocation of memory for memory for array arr is successful";
    delete arr;
    getch();enter code here
}
```

Comment: This adds nothing

Comment: this doesn’t answer the question : in this code you create an array of int, not an array of pointers

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. Can you elaborate on the answer please?