# What does long * tempArray[10]; do?

Tags: c++, arrays, long-integer

Can you please explain what this piece of C++ code does:

```
int main()
{
    long * tempArray[10];
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is pretty basic C stuff. What instructional materials are you using to learn?

Comment: A great resource to help decipher C-style declarations is [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=long+*+tempArray%5B10%5D%3B)

Comment: @user1544818 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an array of pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620843/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-pointers)

Comment: As @GregHewgill said, maybe you should start from the beginning if you are asking what the '*' means, otherwise it might be a painful learning process.

Comment: It multiplies `long` by `tempArray` 10 times.

Comment: @user Please read [Clockwise Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: @dreamlax: I hate to spoil the joke, but some novices might take you seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular snippet of code does nothing at all. If you compile that program, it will terminate and report to the hosting environment that it terminated successfully, and that's it.

The `long * tempArray[10];` declares a variable called `tempArray` to have the type *array 10 of pointer to long*, which means that `tempArray` is capable of holding 10 `long *` objects.

For demonstrative purposes:

```
// declare some long integers
long myLong = 100;
long anotherLong = 400;
long thirdLong = 2100;

// declare array 3 of pointer to long
long *tempArray[3];

// remember that arrays in C and C++ are 0-based, meaning index 0
// refers to the first object in an array. Here we are using the `&'
// operator to obtain a long pointer to each of the longs we declared
// and storing these long pointers in our array.
tempArray[0] = &myLong;
tempArray[1] = &anotherLong;
tempArray[2] = &thirdLong;
```

Answer (score 0):

It creates an array of 10 long pointers.

Comment: what does the asterisk (*) mean?

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't actually do anything.

`long * tempArray[10];` allocates an array capable of holding ten pointers to long integers.