# C++ array of pointers to classes

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

How do I make an array of pointers?
I'm trying to make an array of pointers to a class in order to provide both O(1) access and have O(1) insertion. This is essentially what I've got. It has to be an array of pointers hence `datalist` being a pointer to a pointer. I think this is more of a lack of syntactical knowledge.

```
class Data{

};

class List{

private:

    Data** datalist;

public:
    explicit List(int s = 20):datalist{/* new something */}{}

};
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I make an array of pointers?

Comment: To elaborate a bit further on that, are you asking 1) if your assumptions about the big-O notation are good? 2) if the design of your code is good? 3) if your C++ code is syntactically correct? or 4) if your C++ code is the best way to make the data structure you're describing?  If this is for more than just an exercise, you might want to consider the use of std::vector or explain why that's not what you want; that's probably what I would choose here. (*sigh* crossed timing with the above comment)

Comment: Recommend close as dup of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620843/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-pointers

Comment: A list of lists will not give you O(1) get and put. You need a hashmap for this.

Comment: Yea that's exactly what I should do thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make an array of pointers, you can do it in this way.

```
class Data{

};

class List{

private:

    Data** datalist;

public:
    explicit List(int s = 20):datalist(new Data*[s]) {}

};
```