# Array of pointers C++ creates of copy

Tags: c++

I want to create an array of pointers, and each pointer should keep memory addresses of all elements from another array. But something is goind wrong.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int *b = new int[sizeof(a)];

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++)
    {
        b = &a[i];
    }

    std::cout << &b[3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << &a[3] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I expect is similar memory addresses, and values. Bt everything is different.

Comment: You don't have an array of pointers.

Comment: You have 2 arrays of `int`s, both with other memory addresses. You are just setting their values to the addresses of `a`.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem, but `sizeof(a)` gives the number of **bytes** in the array, which, for an array of `int`, is larger than the number of elements. So `new int[sizeof(a)]` allocates a larger array than you need. If you insist on hand-allocating arrays (instead of using `std::vector`), the number of elements in an array is `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)`.

Comment: &a[3] = b[3]; content of pointer is address

Comment: duplicate of [How do I create an array of pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620843/how-do-i-create-an-array-of-pointers)

Comment: new is totally unnecessary, sizeof performs a compile time operation

Comment: The subscript operator is just syntactic sugar. Meaning: `&a[i] => &*(a + i) => a + i`

Comment: the obvious giveaway here is that each time round that loop you overwrite `b`. So your `new` does nothing (except leak) sice you immediately throw away its return value.. And you only have one `b` value, the last one. You are missing an extra level of indirection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted to do this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    unsigned max=sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    int **b = new int*[max];

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        b[i] = &a[i];
    }

    unsigned max=sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
         std::cout << "b[" << i << "]:" << *b[i] << std::endl;
         std::cout << "a[" << i << "]:" << a[i] << std::endl;
    }
    delete[] b;

    return 0;
}
```

Two mistakes. First, when you declare array of pointers you use

```
int **b;
```

Secondly, to determine size of array you can use

```
sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])
```

but be careful here. After passing your array as argument into function it won't work any longer.

Comment: Since it's all in your main it will be freed anyway. But in general you will need to call delete where you used new previously. If you used new[] use delete[]. As in here delete[] b; (corrected answer)

Comment: @Victor Don't you think `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])); i++)`?

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(a)` returns the size **IN BYTES** of `a`.

To get the number of elements you should divide that for the `sizeof(int)`.

So if you have `5` elements, for example, you'll have `sizeof(a)` equal to `5*sizeof(int)`. Divide that for `sizeof(int)` (which could vary depending on the machine you're working on) and you'll have the exact number of elements.

And I thing you wanna assign `b[i] = &a[i]`, in order to store the addresses in the different elements of `b`.

Comment: 1) Thank you for help with size of arrays;
2) Still I dont understand how to write address of a-elements into pointers (b-elements);